# Import RNCryptor to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes, xcode7

I try to import RNCryptor to my project to encrypt some string. But I have trouble to understand how to import that to my objective-c project. I copied the `RNCryptor/RNCryptor.swift` and `RNCryptor.h` by drag and drop in to my project. Then it "created a bridging header". After that I tried to debug but I have 38 error messages like: `Use of unresolved identifier 'kCCKeySizeAES256'` or `Use of unresolved identifier 'CCPBKDFAlgorithm'`. How can I fix that and how would I use it in a viewController.h file? Normally with `#import "RNCryptor.h"`

https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor#obj-c

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `#import "RNCryptor/RNCryptor.h"` to the bridging header file, did you do that?

See the [RNCryptor Swift branch](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/tree/swift)

> The Bridging Header
>
> CommonCrypto is not a modular header in Xcode 7. This makes it very challenging to import into Swift. To work around this, the necessary header files have been copied into RNCryptor.h, which needs to be bridged into Swift. You can do this either by using RNCryptor as a framework, adding #import "RNCryptor/RNCryptor.h" to your existing bridging header, or making RNCryptor/RNCryptor.h your bridging header in Build Settings, "Objective-C Bridging Header."